# How to know which instance of Python my script is being ran on?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

So I am trying to run a script from task scheduler. It has not been working and in the second that the terminal pops up and disappears, I was able to read it say "ImportError no Module named Pandas" My script imports Pandas fine and runs perfectly, but whenever I double click the script to run or schedule it to run automatically it is saying I do not have Pandas.

My theory is that it is using a different instance of Python that is installed on this computer that does not have the Pandas library installed. However, when i try to reinstall pandas on the command line using pip it sends back "requirement already satisfied". I would appreciate any advice or ideas for me to try. Thank you!

Comment: You are right you are using different versions of Python. `python --version` will give you the default version of Python in your system. You can use a specific version of python by typing `python2.7` or `python3.5` in the terminal. This will give you terminal access to the specific python. Different python versions present in your system will be available in the path: `/usr/lib/python2.X`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sys.version_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info) and [`sys.version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version) contain the version of Python that is being run. [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) contains the path to the specific interpreter running.

Python3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> sys.version
'3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python3'
```

Python2:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python2'
```

The problem seems to be that your registry editor has set a different version set to run "on-click" for Python executables. You can fix that by running the Python installer for the version you want, and setting it to repair, or modifying "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\open\command" to run the correct python executable (Should be "C:\Windows\py.exe"). See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO4qJ.png) for where to find it.

If you are already using py.exe, adding a hashbang to the top of the file (`#!Python<version>`, or to work with Unix executables, `#!/usr/bin/env python<version>`) should help py.exe pick the correct executable to run.

To install using pip for a specific executable, run `Path\To\Executable -m pip install <module>`.

To use modules from a different site-path, add the directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Using `import <file>` will check for modules in directories in the PYTHONPATH.